# Changing foldmarker per filetype with vim 8.2

Tags: vimrc, folding, filetype

On an up-to-date Arch system, I set up marker-based folds in `vim` and `python` scripts like so:

Extracted from my `~/.vimrc` [[1](https://github.com/Cbhihe/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc)]

```
set nocompatible  " default
filetype plugin indent on
set nofoldenable
set foldlevel=1
set foldcolumn=1
```

Along with:

```
$ cat ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim
setlocal foldmethod=marker
setlocal foldmarker={{{,}}}  " Default for fdm=marker

$ cat ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
setlocal foldmethod=marker
setlocal foldmarker={{{,}}}  " Default for fdm=marker
setlocal foldnestmax=3
```

It works for vim scripts but not for python. I've been at it most of one day already and frankly I am missing something. I am currently resorting to committing the content of `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` directly to `~/.vimrc` and setting the corresponding parameters globally instead of locally.  That works well, but that also excludes the possibility of differentiating settings, e.g.:

- marker-based folds in `vim`
- indent-based or syntax-based folds in `python` or in `bash` scripts.

*What am I doing wrong ?*

---

With all setting committed globaly to `~/.vimrc`, what I get in the `vim` buffer of any python module is:

```
: verbose set filetype? foldmethod? foldmarker?
      filetype=python
            Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim line 1291                                                      
      foldmethod=marker
            Last set from ~/.vim/view/~=+Documents=+Work=+Projects=+xxx-data=+Src=+proof_demo.py= line 67
      foldmarker={{{,}}}
            Last set from ~/.vim/view/~=+Documents=+Work=+Projects=+xxx-data=+Src=+proof_demo.py= line 66
```

---

#### What "it doesn't work" means

It doesn't fold at all when I do `zc`, other than where I have previously set fold(s) manually. `zM` has no effect at all (for example when `foldmethod=indent` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`), again except when markers are set manually (provided `foldmethod=marker` in `~/.vimrc`). Same behavior for all python files, which tells me it is probably some deep-seated issue, not malformed python file. Same in shell scripts with a similarly built `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim`, so it's not python specific.

#### Views info

The most interesting use case in that context is when `foldmethod=manual` because, without views, manually set folds are lost upon closing the buffer. But I need views to be able to go back to the buffer's last cursor position (line + col) when re-opening a file with vim. I need views for that because the alternative I did implement before I started using folds, based on [vim.fandom.com/wiki/…](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session), is incompatible with implementing any kind of folds apparently. It just fails silently.

It turns out my use of "views" is not compatible with parsing settings from `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/*.vim` files. "Why ?" is beyond me. I am not sure whether it is the execution context I build by means of my `~/.vimrc` or a bug. I would tend to favor the first, although I really don't have much special in `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: With the setup you described... What does `:verbose set filetype? foldmethod? foldmarker?` return? Wondering if any of your settings are being overwritten elsewhere... When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? It doesn't fold at all? It folds the incorrect blocks? What if you use a command such as `zM` to fold everything? Can you share a small reproducer Python file with the markers where this doesn't do what you expect it to?

Comment: You said *"except when markers are set manually"*, but when you're using `foldmethod=marker`, you **have to** add the markers (manually) for folding to work... Like, you need to add a `# {{{` comment to begin a fold and a `# }}}` to end it. (Or a `# {{{1` comment at each new top-level fold, using an explicit level also works.) Do you by any chance misunderstand how `foldmethod=marker` is supposed to work? See `:help fold-marker`...

Comment: Yeah I thought as much, just wanted to double check... I'm puzzled at why this doesn't work for you, I can't reproduce it really... I'm not that knowledgeable in how Vim folding works, hopefully someone who knows it better than me will pitch in with a better suggestion on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I’m not using views and I’m able to get to the last-edited line with a similar autocommand, folds or no... https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/5aa578e98be7a2fea36f19fc67ecb62e61e27f42/links/vim/plugin/lastpos.vim

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Restoring last cursor position is also in [defaults.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/defaults.vim#L111)

Comment: All, I've spent some time cleaning up the comments (moved relevant info into post). Please delete any others we no longer need. Further discussion can carry into [chat] :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Thanks to @DBenKnoble for his insight. It led me right to the solution.]*

When using "views" to store `vim` sessions snapshots, watch for the value(s) of the `vop` option parameter. For more info `:h vop`. Its default is:

```
set viewoptions=cursor,folds,options,curdir
```

Use of `folds` in the above conflicts with the use of `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/*.vim` files. You can take `folds`out and go on using the two `autocmd` lines below in your `~/.vimrc`. Both call on "views":

```
au BufWinLeave * mkview
au VimEnter * silent loadview
```

Then you can go back to using `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` as you did.  You can check that for any python module:

```
:verbose set filetype? foldmethod? foldmarker?
    filetype=python
         Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim line 1291
    foldmethod=marker
         Last set from ~/.vim/view/~=+.vimrc line 67
    foldmarker={{{,}}}
         Last set from ~/.vim/view/~=+.vimrc line 65
```

So the best thing is to stick to `views` and just suppress the `folds` option in `viewoptions` in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set viewoptions=cursor,options,curdir
```